# Тип char в C#.NET

Tags: c#

Скажите вот я прочитал про такой тип переменной как

```
char
```

Написано, что этот тип может содержать только 1 символ, но вопрос, а где его можно использовать? Ведь есть

```
string
```

Он может принимать сразу много значений... так в чем выгода использовать **char**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String` по своей структуре - это упорядоченная коллекция объектов `char` (их массив)и , вообще говоря, `String` как класс предоставляет удобные методы для работы с этой самой коллекцией.

---

*Тип `char` сам по себе фундаментально необходим, т.к иначе просто невозможно было бы представить себе следующую запись:*

```
string s = "Здорово, Васек!";
// Каким типом данных представлять первую букву, если нет 'char'?
??? firstLetter = s[0];
```

Если подытожить, то **скорее можно было бы представить себе C# без типа `String`, нежели без типа `char`,** поскольку `String` возможно сэмулировать как некоторый `IList<char>` или `IEnumerable<char>` и т.д.

---

*P.S* На деле, конечно, первый абзац не совсем корректен, учитывая, что `String` ведет себя как value type, не являясь им, но это уже не столь принципиально для ответа на вопрос.

Comment: Но тогда почему сколько я смотрел видео-уроков, нигде не упоминалась об этом типе переменной?(а смотрел я их очень много)

Comment: Смотрите поменьше видеоуроков и побольше пишите свои программы.